# PHP Session isn't working on index.php in webroot

Tags: php, session

This is kind of strange.

I'm working with sessions. I have `session_start();` at the beginning of all my first php blocks on each page.

When I echo out a session variable on index.php in webroot (/var/html/www) it gives nothing. If I move index.php to /var/html/www/home or some other non-webroot directory it will echo the variable, no problem.

Is there something special I don't know about sessions?

Comment: an addition of your codes would be a great help .

Comment: You might have a different php.ini being applied. Does `phpinfo()` give you the same output in both places?

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by session file that is being used by php is not accessible or running out of disk space. Check your php.ini to find out the session file location and make sure your php can access that file & folder and you have enough disk space.